# Netbeans does not compile a file

Tags: c, netbeans, compilation, makefile

I have `c` project which imported in `Netbeans` with its makefile. All things go well. But when I have added a new file, I see that `Netbeans` does not compile it?

I think that I must create a new makefile to contains command which compile the new file. But how?

*P.S*: Makefile is created after running `./configure` command.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a `Makefile.am` or possible a `Makefile.in` file in your project, that's the file you have to add the new file. In the case of `Makefile.am` it should be pretty obvious (just look for something ending with `_SOURCES` followed by a list of all source files). If you don't have a `Makefile.am` then you simply have to find where the other source files are and add the new source there.

Comment: I have both of them. I changed `Makefile.am` and added new source,but it was not compiled! Should I change the `Makefile.in` ?